# Batch file - Using all filepaths in a directory

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to run the following code to go through a directory and modify a bunch of autoCAD drawings.

```
FOR %%f in (C:\Users\pzf6bm\Desktop\AutoCad\*.dwg) do start /wait C:\"Program Files"\"Autodesk"\"AutoCAD 2012 - English"\acad.exe “%%f” /b C:\Users\pzf6bm\Desktop\AutoCad\hide.scr
```

It almost works except for one thing, everytime it retrieves the next filepath it adds an ô character to the beginning of the string and a ö to the end of the string. This makes autoCAD not able to open the file to perform the action.

As an example "C:\test.txt" becomes "ôC:\test.txtö" I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: Too many quotes. Use `start /wait "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2012 - English\acad.exe" “%%f”`.

Answer (score 2):

just use right double quotes, not `“%%f”`!

```
"%%f"
```

Comment: Bah, beat me by 23 seconds. :-)

Comment: I had the quotes in incase there is a space somewhere in the filename

Comment: @Endoro - Using quotes around the exe path as you do in your comment requires a quoted title parameter before the exe path.

Comment: @user1296932 - Read Endoro's answer carefully. The quotes you used are totally different then the quotes he is suggesting you use. Fixing the quotes as he suggests will solve your problem.

Comment: IOW, use an editor like EDITPLUS or NOTEPAD++, not a word-processor. Even Notepad - but Notepad may try to "help" by "formatting" for you.

Comment: Ah ok, didn't realize there were different kinds of quotes, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You have smart-quotes around your `%%f` (perhaps you got this from Outlook or Word?).  Retype them as regular quotes and your ô and ö will be gone.

Comment: I had the quotes in incase there is a space somewhere in the filename

Comment: Having quotes isn't a problem, it's the fact that they're smart-quotes (ASCII 147 and 148), not standard double-quotes (ASCII 34).  Retype them by hand instead of copy/pasting and it will work much better.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Normally the `start` command needs a `blank set of quotes after it`, because the first set of quotes is used as the window title.  In your case the fact that c:\ is an unquoted part protects the quoted portions.  Thanks to @dbenham for pointing that out.

Your command (after the `start ""` ) has quotes in an awkward mix, where they should normally be placed at the beginning and end of the `"c:\path\filename.exe"` so see my answer below, with a leading set of blank quotes too.

With modern tools even a short path and filename can be quoted, so it is easy to remember - just quote all terms.

```
FOR %%f in (C:\Users\pzf6bm\Desktop\AutoCad\*.dwg) do start "" /wait "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2012 - English\acad.exe" "%%f" /b "C:\Users\pzf6bm\Desktop\AutoCad\hide.scr"
```

Comment: I think the OP's odd use of quotes in the exe path prevent it from being interpreted as the title.

Comment: @dbenham Yes, you are right.  The leading unquoted c:\ protect the quotes.